# It is possible to insert multiple Mysql data in a single Crystal Report field

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

I have a table in MySQL similar to:

```
     Day                
     Internal Number
     Schedule
```

Is it possible with Crystal Report to create a field that receives, for example, on day 1 all Internal Number at a specific Schedule separated for example by a comma?

exemple:

```
  Schedule --->  |   00H/08H    |    08H/16H    |    16H/24
------------------------------------------------------------
     1st May     |   10,15,18   |       9       |    2,3      <----- Internal Number
------------------------------------------------------------
     2nd May     |              |               |
------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The rows can be Group Footers (Group by by the date field).

Under each column, within the group footer, you can show the values by (concatenating) the Internal Numbers into a global string variable using a detail section formula.

Suppress the detail section so it doesn't show.

Reset all column-wise global string variables in a Group header formula.

Use a Group Footer formula for each column to display the string variable. Typically, that formula also removes an extra delimiter (depending on the concatenation logic).

The same can be done with a subreport but the solution above is simpler and performs much better.